# oracle 12c Testing triggers on views

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have created view in Oracle 12c using the following code:

```
CREATE VIEW ConcertView AS
SELECT a.ConcertNo, a.Concert_Name, a.Price, a.Duration, a.City, b.EventDate, b.Even t_Name
FROM Concert a,Events b 
WHERE a.ConcertNo = b.ConcertNo 
 AND a.ConcertNo != 'CN002'
```

The view creates without any errors. I then create a trigger on the view using the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_month
INSTEAD OF DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON ConcertView

DECLARE
    ConcertDate date;
BEGIN
    IF (to_char(EventDate, 'DD-MM-YY') = 'JUL')  THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Concerts cannot be run during JULY');
    END IF; 
END;

Trigger created.
```

The trigger creates without any errors.

I am trying to ensure that concerts cannot be run during July.
However the trigger does not take any action.  Could anybody please let me know what I am doing wrong, or explain how to test a trigger?

Comment: Why creating trigger on view and not on table? Since there would be no insert or update directly on view, the trigger won't work (as per my understanding)

Comment: the reason why i am testing the trigger on the view is because the view can be dropped at any stage and re-created via joining the 2 tables together again if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this sentence:

```
IF (to_char(EventDate, 'DD-MM-YY') = 'JUL')
```

For this:

```
IF to_char(EventDate, 'MON') = 'JUL'
```

In the first sentence you are comparing the date in the format DD-MM-YY with the name of the month. In the second, you're going to compare the name of the month.

You can check the doc here:
[Oracle Doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

Comment: how do i test if the trigger is working on the view, do i insert into the view the way i would in a table?

Comment: yes, check a look here... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#i2064426 an example of insert with views.

Comment: I have tried the following however it creates with complation error using the following code:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_month
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON ConcertView
DECLARE 
date_check EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF
to_char(EventDate, 'MON') = 'JUL' 
THEN
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Concerts cannot be run during JULY');
END IF;
END;